# Appium Robot framework, Could't open browser on device emulator

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

I have integrated Robot framework with Appium.

Installed the SDK

Started the Appium server

And below is the code I am using:

```
   *** Settings ***
    Library                     AppiumLibrary
    Documentation           A test suite containing tests related to Mobile test     
    Force Tags              MobileTest


    *** Keywords ***

    *** Test Cases ***

    Test Case
        Open Application  http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub  platformName=Android  platformVersion=6.0  deviceName=emulator-5554  app=com.android.browser  automationName=appium  appPackage=com.android.browser  appActivity=AddBookmarkPage
```

I am faced with the following errors:

> WebDriverException: Message: A new session could not be created.
>   (Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while
>   processing the command. (Original error: unknown error:
>   com.android.chrome is not installed on device emulator-5554
>
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845
>   (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1
>   x86_64)))

Any advice on how to tackle this?

Comment: perhaps  you need to install com.android.chrome on the emulator?

Comment: @BryanOakley In Open Application keyword, there is 1 parameter app=com.android.browser then why is it looking for chrome

Comment: I don't know, but the error message certain implies that it is.

Comment: did u try to change parameter app=com.android.browser to  => browserName=Browser ?